# How to send mail in FreeBSD using variables of file paths in scripts?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, freebsd

We used to have a mail command which worked on Solaris platform, the command was

`mail -t $MAILTO < ${SCRIPTROOT}abc.txt`

abc.txt is the file name which was used as subject.

Now we migrated to FreeBSD and the mail is not coming. I removed the -t flag, the mail came, but the text came in body of mail. If I put -s flag on abc.txt , the complete path of abc.txt is showing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the content of `abc.txt` as the subject of the mail. That would be achieved by the following:

```
mail -s "`cat abc.txt`" ${RECIPIENT} < ${FILE_WITH_MAIL_BODY}
```

Comment: the mail did come when I put the text file between double quotes and backticks . but the body still did not come. Actually I'm calling this mail command from another function which calls the mail function like `Send_Mail "${SUBJECT}" "${TO}" MSG_TEXT.txt ` ...if it remains this way, I'm getting the mail but no body, if I put < symbol before the messagebody text, I'm not getting the mail at all.

Comment: Well, can you send a mail like that from the command line (i.e. outside of your shell script) at all? A minimal example of your (non-working) code would be required for further diagnosis.

Comment: `echo "${2}" > MSG_TEXT.txt
  echo "\n" >> MSG_TEXT.txt
  cat ${ROOTDIR}${FOLDER}parms/file_logs.txt >> MSG_TEXT.txt
  echo "\n" >> MSG_TEXT.txt
  cat $PMRootDir/temp/result_output.txt >> MSG_TEXT.txt
  Send_Mail "${SUBJECT}" "${TO}" "`cat MSG_TEXT.txt`" ` In this code snippet you can see the , the mail is coming, but the MSG_TEXT.txt file are not being appended by the result_output.txt , Any mistake here?

Comment: `Send_Mail` is a function in your shell script, I assume? You cannot use `<` to redirect input when calling the function, then, but you have to do it inside of the function, where you execute `mail`.

Comment: yes `Send_Mail` is in my shell script, its a function. I used multiple switch cases to modify how the mail is built for sending. currently I think `cat $PMRootDir/temp/result_output.txt >> MSG_TEXT.txt` is causing the error, as the txt file is not appending to the msg_text